# Regex Replace - TextBox Text to ONLY Include Floating Values

Tags: c#, wpf

#### Revised

I'm trying to make a Regex Expression that parsed floating point numbers.

1. At most 1 negative (-)
2. At most 1 decimal (.)
3. At most 3 digits to the left of the decimal
4. At most 3 digits to the right of the decimal

I'm at the point where I tried the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(([\-]?|[\.]?|[\-\.]?|[0-9]?)([0-9]{0,3}))");
bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch(text);
```

However, inputs like "--" still pass

Comment: This is supposed to be a challenging question

Comment: Can you please explain why "bool isMatch = Single.TryParse(text, myFloat);" won't serve your purposes?

Comment: "--" passes because it matches on the first "-", and the rest of the string is ignored.  If you add $ to the end of the regular expression, then the entire string will need to match your reg ex.  However, you will then discover new errors in your reg ex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to do regex:

How about ^-{0,1}\d{0,3}(?:.{0,1}(?<=.)\d{0,3})?$

[Here it is with some test values](http://rubular.com/r/QGSb2s0WOV)

with regards to the onchange event.  I don't know what format you're using.  In MVVM, the binding will keep the box from being changed incorrectly.  In windows forms, you'll, have to change it yourself.  I'd say store the value whenever it's good to a private property.  THen, if the change is invalid, return to the previous value.

additionally, the test in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex rx = new Regex(@"^-{0,1}\d{0,3}(?:\.{0,1}(?<=\.)\d{0,3})?$");
            List<string> testStrings = new List<string>()
            {
                "100",
                "100.100",
                "1000.0000",
                "100000",
                "-1",
                "-1.234",
                "--",
                "100.100ab",
                "1,234.1",
                "1,234",
                "abc",
                "abc123.123",
                "abc.def"
            };
            foreach(var str in testStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}", str, rx.IsMatch(str)));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: of course not "as the Text_Changed event gets fired I want to validate the text to make sure its still a float, double, or int (no commas or currency)." <-- you didn't want -. - to work

Comment: I know I typed -- and The Regex didn't change it to -

Comment: regex replace?  How is - -- a point, float, double, or int.  You shouldn't vote down my answer for something that isn't even listed in your question.

Comment: I dont think you understand the question. If the user types - followed by - the second - should be gone

Comment: you said that, but you ALSO said (twice) "NO NEGATIVES" so I can only assume that the - was a mistake.  If you want negatives to be allowed, you'd need to add a - to the front, like so ^-{0,1}\d{0,3}\.{0,1}\d{0,3}$

Comment: It was in his question but your answer is still helpful.  Your answer shows more research than the question. +1 and -1

Comment: This works but this solution only supports a maximum digit count of 6. I need it so max 3 before and max 3 after a decimal. If no decimal then max 3 digits

Comment: that's a bit more complicated. but updating my answer once more

Answer (score 1):

If you follow mbeckish's solution with TryParse, and hook it into the Validating event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx, you should be good to go.

If you need to use regex (which you may, if you're doing this on every key press), you can use this, which has worked for me in the past:

^-?\d*\.?(\d+[eE]?[-+]?(\d{1,3})?)?$

For your digit count requirements, you can replace the \d* and \d+ with \d{0,3} and \d{1,3}, respectively.

Comment: It does for me - I'm not able to type -- without my validator rejecting it and deleting the second -.

Comment: What you are making IS a validator.  So is the code that I wrote that is in a shipping product and which does exactly what you are asking it to do.  If you'd like to be less cryptic and give your requirements up front in the question, you might get an answer you like.  Until then, you will continue to be frustrated at our inability to guess at what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regular expressions, you can use Single.TryParse to verify that the string is a valid representation of a single precision float.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - Quoting your question: "I am in the process of creating a Regex expression to parse a TextBox text so only floating point values can be pressed...Basically as the Text_Changed event gets fired I want to validate the text to make sure its still a float, double, or int (no commas or currency)." Your stated objective is to validate that the text is a valid representation of a float.  Single.TryParse performs that validation.  Maybe you should rephrase your question if you have something else in mind (like automatically transforming invalid text into valid text).

Comment: The title says Regex and I don't see that from your example

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - Again, you should rephrase the question to precisely state your objectives.  The title alone does not sufficiently explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It doesn't matter WHY I'm doing it. Its the situation im in where I have to use it.

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI - I'm asking you to explain WHAT you want to do, not WHY.  In the body of your question, you are talking about validation.  Validation is checking whether the text is valid, which is what TryParse will accomplish.  I have a feeling what you really want is not validation, but transformation of invalid text into valid text.  If that is what you want, you should rephrase your question.  Seems like every answer provided so far is for validation, because that's how your question is phrased.